# Basic macro I wrote is opening two workbooks (one named and saved as intended, one blank) - why?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a basic macro (very new to VBA) that extracts two columns from a workbook and puts them into a new workbook which I name and save. This works fine, but when I run it it opens and saves one as intended (e.g. "Health Care Portfolio") and opens (but doesn't name/save) a second blank book (with the standard "Book #" name). An excerpt of my code is below, could someone point out why this is happening? Thank you

```
Sub CreateHealthcare()

Sheets("Health Care").Select

    With Application
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
        .Workbooks.Add
            With Workbooks.Add

                Workbooks("TVL Portfolio Creator.xlsm").Sheets("Health Care").Range("D:D").Copy
                .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Workbooks("TVL Portfolio Creator.xlsm").Sheets("Health Care").Range("E:E").Copy
                .Sheets(1).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                .Sheets(1).Name = "Health Care Portfolio"

            End With

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\example\Health Care Portfolio" & Format(Now(), " DDMMMYY") _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You've got `Workbooks.Add` twice. Remove the first one and add a dot in front of the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me your intention is for only 1 new workbook to be created and saved. 
Your code contains the     `workbooks.add` statement twice.
So taking the first out, should solve your problem.

If that doesn't work, I would recommend declaring a `Workbook object`, and referencing that.

Also the line `Sheets("Health Care").Select` doesn't really do anything since your copy-statements include an explicit reference.

Your code would look something like this:

```
Sub CreateHealthcare()
Dim NewBook as Workbook

    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

            With NewBook

                Workbooks("TVL Portfolio Creator.xlsm").Sheets("Health Care").Range("D:D").Copy
                .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                Workbooks("TVL Portfolio Creator.xlsm").Sheets("Health Care").Range("E:E").Copy
                .Sheets(1).Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                .Sheets(1).Name = "Health Care Portfolio"

            End With

        NewBook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\example\Health Care Portfolio" & Format(Now(), " DDMMMYY") _
, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

    End With

End Sub
```